# Does Android productFlavors need separate application in google dev console?

Tags: android, build.gradle

I would like to have 2 different applications in google playstore : "My App Free" and "My App Pro". From the research I have made for this subject, the best way for that is to use productFlavors so here is an extract of my build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
    }
}

productFlavors {
    free {
        ...
    }
    pro {
        applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
    }
}
```

When I try to build the build variant myapp-pro-release, I get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':myapppro:processProReleaseGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.myapp.pro'
```

Does that mean that I have to add a dedicated my-app-pro app in google dev console that would have com.myapp.pro as applicationId? Or is there an other way to fix the error of build with gradle?

Comment: If you are using Google play services or firebase services you have to register all the packages that you are using and update the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate new google-service.json with package name `com.myapp.pro` and place it in `app/src/pro`

Comment: Thanx, and do I have to add an app with com.myapp.pro in dev console to have 2 different versions of the app in google play store?